# Why can't I select form elements by name and use their value to set a variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the value of a group of radio buttons and use it to set a variable. The idea is that the variable will change every time the radio button is changed.

For some reason this doesn't seem to be working, and I have no idea why. The variable doesn't seem to be changing from the initially defined '0'. The variable should be displayed in an alert box when the yellow button is pressed.

I've put together a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve - see below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var paytype = 0;

 $("input [name = paytype]").change(function(){
  var paytype = $(this).val();
  });

 $("#button").click(function(){
  alert ( paytype );
  });
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="enrolmentform" action="thanks.php">

<input type="radio" name="paytype" id="bacs" value="Bank Transfer" />
<label for="bacs">Bank Payment/BACS Transfer</label>
<input type="radio" name="paytype" id="cheque" value="Cheque" />
<label for="cheque">Cheque</label>
<input type="radio" name="paytype" id="card" value="Card" />
<label for="card">Card</label>

<div style="width:45px; height: 20px; background-color: yellow; border: thin solid black; margin-top: 20px;"><a href="#" id="button">Button</a></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
$("input:radio[name='paytype']").change(function(){
 paytype = $(this).val();
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/mCdz9/)

Comment: This was the right answer. The key problem was specifying just 'input' instead of 'input:radio'

Comment: @Chris this solution does work but not becasue `:radio` was added. It works because the `paytype` variable is not re-declared inside the `.change()` function, like some of the other answers have pointed out. It is also worth noting that `:radio` is officially deprecated from the jQuery API and it _may_ be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 6):

Your declaring paytype twice.   You don't need `var`:

```
$("input [name = paytype]").change(function(){
    paytype = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are re defining your variable in this line

```
var paytype = $(this).val();
```

replace it with

```
paytype = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var paytype = 0;

 $("input [name = paytype]").change(function(){
  paytype = $(this).val();
  });

 $("#button").click(function(){
  alert ( paytype );
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go,
there were few minor mistakes..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">            </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var paytype;

 $("input[name='paytype']").change(function(){
   paytype = $(this).val();
  });

 $("#button").click(function(){
  alert ( paytype );
  });
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="enrolmentform" action="thanks.php">

<input type="radio" name="paytype" id="bacs" value="Bank Transfer" />
<label for="bacs">Bank Payment/BACS Transfer</label>
<input type="radio" name="paytype" id="cheque" value="Cheque" />
<label for="cheque">Cheque</label>
<input type="radio" name="paytype" id="card" value="Card" />
<label for="card">Card</label>

<div style="width:45px; height: 20px; background-color: yellow; border: thin solid     black; margin-top: 20px;"><a href="#" id="button">Button</a></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```